# Why does fread segfault?

Tags: c, linux

I have been tasked with implementing an ls function for files in an .iso file system. I need to use fread but it is segfaulting. I know the file exists and i know it has data in it. I have the format for calling fread and I have set it up as follows

```
static void ls(File *file, int32_t root_dir_size)
{
   void* sector;
   int result;
   result = fread(sector, 1, 1, file);
}
```

Why does this segfault? I am new to C and I am coming from C++ so not sure what I am missing here.

Comment: `sector` is uninitialized. `File` --> `FILE` ?

Comment: You'd have the same issue in C++.

Comment: **sector** needs to point to an empty storage area. An array or block of memory from **malloc()**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fread` needs memory into which to put the data it's reading. That memory is pointed to by the first parameter, in your case `sector`. However, you have not initialized `sector`. You will need to allocate some memory, in this case just one byte and have `sector` point to that. For instance:

```
void *sector = malloc(1);
```

As always, don't forget to free the memory after you're done using it.

Comment: Alright thanks for the clarification. So in C if I declare a pointer I have to always allocate memory or is this just the case for the void pointer?

Comment: You can have a pointer point to anything, malloc'd memory, an existing variable, even functions. Using allocated memory is probably the most common use. It's fairly uncommon so actually declare a void pointer. Most pointers are typed (primitive types, structs, etc.). `fread` takes a void pointer because it simply writes data, byte-by-byte, into the memory pointed to. `void` is used to show that the type of the pointer doesn't matter, you just need to use a pointer of some sort.

Comment: You are specifically referring to void pointers that can point to anything?

Comment: I just mean you can have `int x = 0; int *xPtr = &x;` Just to illustrate you can have a pointer without involving malloc at all.

Comment: Why not just declare a local variable and pass its address to the function? There doesn't seem to be a need for dynamic allocation in this function.

Comment: @MichaelAlbers Okay I see what yo uare saying. I actually have to read 2048 bytes from the file at 1 time though as it is the size of 1 sector on the disk so just using an int would not be sufficient unless I am missing something.

Comment: @user3577756 Right an int isn't anywhere near sufficient. That was just for illustrative purposes. You'd need to allocate 2048 bytes then.